# Remover duplicados de array jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo un script para generar una grafica con ChartsJS usando los datos que traigo de una tabla. El problema es que hay unos datos que el php manda duplicados pero son necesarios para que el JSON se cree bien.

Este es el JSON que el archivo PHP me regresa:

```
[
 {
  tiro: "TD",
  fecha: "Enero 2019",
  m3: "383.5"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TB",
  fecha: "Enero 2019",
  m3: "114"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TD",
  fecha: "Febrero 2019",
  m3: "422.5"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TB",
  fecha: "Febrero 2019",
  m3: "39"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TD",
  fecha: "Marzo 2019",
  m3: "500"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TB",
  fecha: "Marzo 2019",
  m3: "96.5"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TD",
  fecha: "Abril 2019",
  m3: "915"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TB",
  fecha: "Abril 2019",
  m3: "75"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TD",
  fecha: "Mayo 2019",
  m3: "128.5"
 },
 {
  tiro: "TB",
  fecha: "Mayo 2019",
  m3: "31"
 }
]
```

Como se puede ver las fechas son los datos duplicados, eso es lo que quiero arreglar en el script que es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    url : "tiro_mes_ajax.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function (data){
        console.log(data);

        var m3 = {
            fecha : [],
            TD : [],
            TB : []
        };

        var len = data.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){

            m3.fecha.push(data[i].fecha);

            if (data[i].tiro == "TD"){
                m3.TD.push(data[i].m3);
            }
            else if (data[i].tiro == "TB"){
                m3.TB.push(data[i].m3);
            }
        }

        console.log(m3);

        var ctx = $("#bar-chartcanvas");

        var data = {
            labels : m3.fecha,

            datasets : [
                {
                    label : "M3 TD",
                    data : m3.TD,
                    backgroundColor : "blue",
                    borderColor : "lightblue",
                    fill : false,
                    lineTension : 0,
                    pointRadius : 5
                },
                {
                    label : "M3 TB",
                    data : m3.TB,
                    backgroundColor : "green",
                    borderColor : "lightgreen",
                    fill : false,
                    lineTension : 0,
                    pointRadius : 5
                }
            ]

        };

        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type : "line",
            data : data,
            options: {}
        });
    },
    error : function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});});
```

Y de momento en la pagina esto es lo que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo quiero eliminar los duplicados o hacer el push de las fechas une vez.

De antemanto muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer.  Las fechas son iguales pero los valores son diferentes porque tienes dos series.  Quieres graficar solo una linea?

Comment: No. Como decia en el texto, solo quiero evitar el duplicado de las fechas, ya que en el script las uso para los titulos del eje X de la grafica. Si ves la imagen, cada mes esta 2 veces, solo quiero que este 1 vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si sabes que las fechas siempre se van a repetir dos veces, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){            

        if (data[i].tiro == "TD"){
            m3.TD.push(data[i].m3);
            m3.fecha.push(data[i].fecha);
        }
        else if (data[i].tiro == "TB"){
            m3.TB.push(data[i].m3);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, eso era todo lo que necesitaba, solo que no sabia como aplicarlo.